# How does the Chrome installer work?

Tags: installation

When you click on the install button, it starts installing right away and does not ask for administrative rights at all. How does it work? How can I replicate it for my own application?

Comment: Chrome simply installs itself in your user directory. As it's a directory you have owner rights to, it doesn't have to ask for administrative rights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By having your application, like Chrome, install itself somewhere secret-ish in among the user's own files, so that it is available only to that user and not to other people on the same machine. (And by having it, like Chrome, not do things while it runs that require admin rights.)

You and your users may not actually want this. It depends on things like

- Whether it matters that the program gets installed only for one user
- Whether there are any security concerns with having the user able to modify the executable without admin rights
- Whether there's any reason for caring where the executable actually ends up living.

Comment: From the users' perspective, apart from not being installed for all users on the machine, what difference does it make?

Comment: Only that it isn't installed for all users. (And, for users who like to poke around, that it (1) isn't installed where they might expect and (2) is somewhere where they're allowed to fiddle with it without admin rights.)

Comment: Incidentally, if whoever downvoted my answer happens to be reading this, I'd be very glad to know why the downvote. If I've said something wrong, I'd like to fix my brain. Thanks!

Comment: I accidentally clicked the downvote arrow instead of accepting, then went on to do other things, and when I realized it was already locked in. If you can make a tiny edit to the post, I can remove it.

Comment: Oh, OK! I've made an edit that also expands a bit on my previously-maybe-cryptic final remark.

Comment: Great, I could remove it. Also, that edit actually adds value, so all is good :)

Comment: I was just installing Chrome and was wondering the same thing as the OP. I downvoted your answer because you are saying why you would not want to do what Chrome does (fair enough), but you're not really answering the question - which is *how* do they do it (I was curious, because Chrome install starts without actually downloading and starting an executable...)

Comment: Found an answer here: http://superuser.com/questions/238357/how-does-google-chrome-installer-work